# How to change input "id" in FormType.php Symfony 4

Tags: forms, symfony4, symfony-4.4

I have tried to change the attr **"id"** in a **FormType.php** file :

```
->add('content', TextareaType::class,([
    'label' => "Description détaillée",
    'attr' => [
        'placeholder' => "Donnez une description qui donne vraiment envoe de venir chez vous !",
        'id' => "test_id"
     ]
]))
```

NB : I WANT TO CHANGE ONLY THE **"ID"**

Thank you

Comment: I think you should set "id" sibling label and attr

Answer (score 1):

you can't add the `id` in controller, but you can add it in the view, like this:

```
{{ form_row(form.content, { 'id': 'test_id' }) }}
```